# Android Step type GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to achieve a design for recycler view in grid layout style. Any Input towards achieving it is very helpful.

I have to design for span size 2 only.

Design :

[image]

I tried to use GridLayoutManager with span size 2

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that list should scroll horizontally and each next column should be following of previous one. I think you can done it by horizontal recycler view with items that contain two views and top space margin which increases sequentially.
Height of the RecyclerView should be calculated and set by last column in code.